# Polling my E-Mail for new Messages with Python

Tags: python, email, imaplib

I have a problem with my Python code.
The code shall read from a E-Mail Inbox (hostet by Strato) and react to new E-Mails.
The background is using it as a alarm monitor for the volunteer firefighter station i am active at.
If there is a fire we get an E-Mail and i want to display the information on a screen using a web-interface.

All workes fine for about 15 to 20 hours then the skript crashes with the error

> ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen.

(I am from Germany. Translatet it shall be something like "an existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host")

This is my code to connect to the E-Mail Inbox

```
#Login ins Postfach
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.strato.de")
mail.login(Mailbenutzer, Mailpasswort)

### holen wir die E-Mails ab ###
mail.select("inbox")
mail.list()

result, data=mail.uid('search', None, "ALL")

inbox_item_list = data[0].split()
most_recent = inbox_item_list[-1]
    oldest = inbox_item_list[0]
    result2 , email_data = mail.uid('fetch', oldest, '(RFC822)')
    raw_email = email_data[0][1].decode("utf-8")
    email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email)

    Rohtext = email_message.get_payload()
```

with the variable "Rohtext" i will do some string-work and get my information i want.
after reading everything and writing it to a MySQL Database i end the connection with the commands

```
mail.close()
mail.logout()
```

so i thought i start a new connection every time i call my function deal with the stuff in the E-Mail and then end the connection so there would be no open connection for ever.

It has been veeeeery long since i started python coding and i havent done it for long so most code for the E-mail connection and reading of the last mail ist copied from the internet. Please dont judge the code if it is bad :D

Every help to write better code will help me evolve my programming.

I am very thankful for every help. If there is more detail needed please tell me.

Kind regards
Christoph Renner

Comment: Also if i can increase the quality of my question please give me some advice :D

Comment: Why don't you load the script again, when the site disconnects you?

Comment: Just put in a sleep and a loop...

Comment: @PetrL. how do i automaticly reload it?

Comment: @ChristophRenner put your script in a function and run it again?